# HoloLens Geolocation Scenarios

Tags: hololens

I have a number of required business cases for HoloLens that require the device to understand a general geolocation, such as the current wearer longitude and latitude within 10 meters or so, as well as sending location information to and from an endpoint during various processes. Users WILL have a mobile device with geolocation capabilities that could assist in the process if necessary, and could also be used as a WiFi hotspot.

Is this a reasonable and reliable use case for HoloLens? Can apps be created that use geolocation and maintain connectivity during an experience, either on their own or with real-time communication to and from a mobile device that has these capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - definitely is a realistic scenario.  I've done some integration between a blue-tooth GPS and the Hololens.  Let me know the particular device you're looking at and I'll see if I can get it working with the Hololens. //Lance Larsen (Microsoft MVP) - www.lancelarsen.com

Comment: Since I'm really just trying to validate some internal "business cases" from Microsoft that will rely on GPS and remote endpoint communication, it's really enough to just be able to say: "Yes, these scenarios are totally reasonable, based on the HoloLens device specifications" as long as users have a pair-able, connected device. Agree?